# Passenger ('Bundler:RubyVersionMismatch')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I'm having a problem  with deploying my rails app on my server. I'm deploying using Passenger for serving up pages. The following error is listed on my page when I start the server. It seems like the version of passenger I have installed is referencing ruby 1.8.7 but my app has been built in 2.0.0. I've tried removing ruby 1.8.7 and reinstalling Passenger, but no luck so far. If I run ruby -v from my directory it lists the version as 2.0.0.

```
Your Ruby version is 1.8.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:361:in `   validate_ruby!'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger- 4.0.0.rc4/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:212:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc4/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:73:in `preload_app'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc4/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:127
```

My apache2.conf file has the following additions:

```
Include sites-enabled/
<ifmodule mod_ssl.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
</ifmodule>
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger 4.0.0.rc4/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc4
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

Edit: ANSWER

I was using sudo to install passenger and apache2 module. Should have just typed:

```
gem install passenger -pre
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

WITHOUT sudo.

Comment: Try doing `bundle update` in the same directory where your Gemfile is located.

Comment: Thanks fmendez, I have tried this but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

your passenger config is pointing to ruby 1.8

```
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger 4.0.0.rc4/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc4
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

It should probably look something like this...

```
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger 4.0.0.rc4/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc4
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby2.0.0
```

Passenger installation is very helpful and it prints these lines for you on the console after successful installation. You should just copy those lines and paste them into your apache conf

Comment: Yep I just figured this out as well. I think you are right.. but here is the strange thing: in /var/lib/gems the only version available is 1.8. However in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ ruby 2.0.0 exists. I could use that path but /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/apache2/ does not contain a mod_passenger.so ... it only has mod-passenger.c... so it seems the passenger-install-apache2-module step needs to be run here.. but when I run this I just get the same old load module. Any ideas?

Comment: check the bin folder inside your ruby 2.0 installation for passenger-install-apache2-module executable. Run that. If it does not exist, then install passenger gem using a rubygem that is installed on ruby 2.0. If path is causing you problems, use absolute path

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was making a stupid mistake using sudo to install the module. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You should try install passenger again.

Comment: Thanks, Dev. I have tried this.. still having the issue though.

Comment: Can you specify the issues. I faced the same problem, previously I have passenger that I install with ruby 1.9.3 after I upgrade to 2.0 I faced that issue. Then I install the passenger using ruby 2.0 and then add passenger configuration to the apache and then it works. And If you are hosting many ruby versions on the your server you or you are hosting some of rails apps that still depend on ruby 1.8.7 or ruby 1.9.3 you should be more careful, since I am not so sure that you can run many instances of passengers (based on different ruby versions) at the same time.

Comment: My server is only running this app. I shouldn't need anything interpreted using 1.8.7, that was just the original version that was installed. I have already uninstalled 1.8 using rvm, which is weird because when I reinstall passenger, it seems to want to use gems from ruby 1.8. I'm not interested in using multiple versions of passenger, just want the version compatible with 2.0.0.

Comment: From what I see the ruby interpreter that passenger is using is still ruby 1.8.7. "From the page - Ruby interpreter command
/usr/bin/ruby1.8".

Comment: try installing the passenger again. If you are using gem install passenger make sure you use the right gem. try using this command to check if you are using the gem executable for ruby 2.0- which gem.

Comment: It says I am using the gem: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/gem but after reinstall of passenger it still gives me the same.

Comment: It seems like an issue with an environment variable pointing to the wrong gemfile.. not sure how to fix it though

Comment: If I switch to root, the ruby -v is 1.8.7... it seems this may be the problem. I'm going to install rvm on root and update version. Then use 2.0.0. Uninstall passenger gem, reinstall.

Comment: I see that you are using the right gem. try execute gem install passenger. If all goes well at the end of the install there will be instruction of setup passenger for apache and setup passenger for ngix . Select the one that are you using. If all goes well. You will see the another instruction to add configuration to the apache or ngix server script. Try remove the old passenger configuration and add the new configuration instead. I think this will fix the issue.

Comment: I've installed 2.0.0 on the root and made it the use version. I uninstalled/removed passenger, reinstalled and I'm still having the problem. The load module that is created when I run 'sudo passenger-install-apache2-module' is still referencing 1.8 gems. But if I try 'which passenger', it returns '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/passenger'. Not sure what to try next... are there other things I should try reinstalling in conjunction with passenger?

Comment: Have you restart apache. Please show the configuration that you added to apache.

Comment: I have tried restarting apache. I've edited my .conf additions in the initial problem description above. The load module references ruby1.8 .. seems it should reference 2.0 but this is the loadmodule generated by the passenger-install-apache2-module step. Think I could just change the values to 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

This is why I switched from using RVM to RBENV. You won't run into this problem with RBENV. Plus its just [better](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Why-rbenv%3F).

If you upgrade ruby using RVM on your production server, you'll be forced to reinstall passenger/nginx (in your case it looks like just passenger).

Huge pain, and causes server downtime.

Use RBENV instead to save yourself this headache. With RBENV/Capistrano, upgrading can simply be done via your gemfile, and the rest just works.